# Show that $I^{(n)}$ is a primary ideal belonging to $P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, localization

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity, $P$ a proper prime ideal in $A$, $I$ a primary ideal belonging to $P$ and $n$ a positive integer. The ideal $(I^{n})^{ec}$ (extension and contraction being made with respect to $A_P=S^{-1}A$, where  $S =A\setminus P$), denoted by $I^{(n)}$, is called the *$n$-th symbolic power* of $I$. Show that $I^{(n)}$ is a primary ideal belonging to $P$.

(I noticed that $A/P$ is a domain , so $S'^{-1}\frac{A}{P}$ is a field. I think that $\frac{S^{-1}A}{S^{-1}P}$ is isomorphic with $S'^{-1}\frac{A}{P}$,  where $S'$=$A$/$P$-{$0$},  so $P^e$ is a maximal ideal in $S^{-1}A$.)

I know just the basic theory about primary ideals, so I need a detailed proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{I^n R_p}=pR_p$ is maximal ideal of $R_p.$ [So](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649146/an-ideal-whose-radical-is-maximal-is-primary?lq=1) $I^n R_p$ is primary ideal of $R_p.$ (Till here you know).

Hence its contraction is primary (This is [Lemma 4.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=Oi4x9NznFEUC&q=Then+I+is+primary+if+and+only+if+the+ring+R%2FI+is+not+trivial+and+has+the+property#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the book Steps in Commutative Algebra by Sharp).