# Ideal generated by an element

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, notation

> Let $R\left [ x \right ]$ denote the set of all polynomials with real coefficients and let A denote the subset of all polynomials with
> constant term 0.
>
> Then A is an ideal of $R\left [ x \right ]$ and$ A=\left \langle x \right \rangle.$

Attempt to verify the above:

> Let $A =\left \{ p\left ( x \right ) \in R\left [ x \right ] \mid p\left ( x \right ) \text{has constant term 0} \right \}$

Using the Ideal test:

Suppose $X\left ( x \right ),Y\left ( x \right ) \in A.$

Then, by the ideal test, $X\left ( x \right )+\left ( -\left ( Y\left ( x \right ) \right ) \right ) \in A$

Now, suppose $R\left ( x \right ) \in R\left [ x \right ] and p\left ( x \right ) \in A.$

Then, $R\left ( x \right )\cdot p\left ( x \right ) \in A$ since the constant term $0$ in $p\left ( x \right )$ kills any constant term.

Thus, A is an ideal of $R\left [ x \right ]$.

To show that $A=\left \langle x \right \rangle, $

$x = \left \{ x^{1},x^{2},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,x^{n} \right \}$

Then, $\left \langle x \right \rangle=\left \{ \alpha_{1}x^{1}+\cdot \cdot \cdot +\alpha_{n}x^{n} \right \}$
and I suppose we would have shown that this is equivalent to A.

But what confuses me is the notation for $\left \langle x \right \rangle$.

Shouldn't $\left \langle x \right \rangle=\left \{ x^{1},x^{2},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,x^{n} \right \}$ according to cyclic notation?

Comment: For a ring $R$, the notation $\langle a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\rangle$ denotes the set $\{a_1m_1+a_2m_2+\ldots+a_nm_n\mid m_i\in R~\forall~1\leq i\leq n\}$

Comment: So, in particular, $\langle x\rangle=\{x\cdot p(x):p(x)\in R[x]\}$. Writing $x=\{x^1,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$ or $\langle x\rangle=\{x^1,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$ is incorrect.

Comment: yes that would be incorrect! context matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a ring $R$, if $a$ is an element then $\langle a\rangle$ usually denotes the ideal generated by $a$, that is the smallest ideal of $R$ contaning $a$, which is $Ra$ (in particular it contains all $a^n$, but not only).

Comment: Several textbooks use $(a)$ with the same meaning.

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you're talking about an expression like $\langle x \rangle$ in an algebraic structure, it is always with respect to the operations in the structure.

If $x$ is in a semigroup and you're only talking about a subsemigroup generated by $x$, then you only have multiplication, and $\langle x\rangle=\{x,x^2, x^3, x^3,\ldots \}$.

If $x$ is in a group and you're talking about the subgroup generated by $x$, then you need to incorporate multiplication and inverses, so not only do you have the powers of $x$, you also need their inverses (so that $\langle x\rangle$ is a group) and in that case $\langle x\rangle=\{\ldots,x^{-2},x^{-1},1,x,x^2, x^3, x^3,\ldots \}$.

If you're talking about an ideal of a ring $R$, then both addition AND multiplication need to be incorporated into generating the ideal. The set $\{\ldots, -3x, -2x, -x, 0, x, 2x, 3x,\ldots\}$ isn't necessarily closed under multiplication by elements of $R$, and the set $\{x, x^2, x^3, \dots\}$ is not necessarily closed under addition.

Here is a rundown of the definition of what a principal ideal is in rings:

1. For a ring, not necessarily with unity:
   $$
   \langle x\rangle=\left\{zx+\sum_{i=1}^n r_ixs_i\mid r_i, s_i\in R, n\in \mathbb N, z\in \mathbb Z\right\}
   $$
2. If the ring has identity, then it is no longer necessary to have the  $zx$ part, since $1$ is available to be $r_i, s_i$ or both:
   $$
   \langle x\rangle=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n r_ixs_i\mid r_i, s_i\in R, n\in \mathbb N\right\}
   $$
3. If $R$ is commutative with identity, this simplifies further since you can combine the $r_i$'s and $s_i$'s:
   $$
   \langle x\rangle=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n xr_i\mid r_i\in R, n\in \mathbb N\right\}=\{xr\mid r\in R\}
   $$
4. If your ring is commutative without identity, you can still combine $r_i$'s and $s_i$'s, but you need to bring back the integer combinations of $x$:

$$
\langle x\rangle=\{xr+xz\mid r\in R, z\in \mathbb Z\}
$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why in a ring without unity the elements have that form?

Comment: @some_math_guy You can easily check that it is the smallest ideal containing $x$.  If you're stuck doing that, you'll have to say where before I can help.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\langle f(x) \rangle$ refers to the ideal generated by the polynomial $f(x)$ and it is defined to be the set $\{ f(x) g(x): g(x) \in R[x]\}$ of all multiples of $f(x)$ in $R[x]$.  For example, $\langle x \rangle$ is the set of all polynomials of the form $x g(x)$, which is exactly the set of all polynomials in $R[x]$ whose constant term is 0.