# Prove that an ideal $q$ whose radical is a maximal ideal is a primary ideal. That is, if $xy\in q$, then $x\in q$ or $y^n \in q$ for some $n>0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have this rough idea: if $\mathrm{rad}(q)$ is maximal, then $R/\mathrm{rad}(q)$ is a field. Consider  $xy \in\mathrm{rad}(q)$, so $(x+\mathrm{rad}(q))(y+\mathrm{rad}(q))=\mathrm{rad}(q)$ is the additive identity. Thus either $x\in\mathrm{rad}(q)$ or $y\in\mathrm{rad}(q)$.

Would that be enough? If $R$ is commutative, would that be enough if I say that either of them must be in $\mathrm{rad}(q)$?

Comment: Of course it's not enough! You have only proved that a maximal ideal is prime.

Answer (score 1):

> Consider  $xy \in\mathrm{rad}(q)$ so $(x+\mathrm{rad}(q))(y+\mathrm{rad}(q))=\mathrm{rad}(q)$

Why only in $\mathrm{rad}(q)$? In your (title) question you are hypothesizing that $xy\in q$. No matter, we will see that it doesn't matter much shortly. (Incidentally, it would be better to write the right hand side as an actual coset: $(x+\mathrm{rad}(q))(y+\mathrm{rad}(q))=0+\mathrm{rad}(q)$.)

> Thus either $x\in\mathrm{rad}(q)$ or $y\in\mathrm{rad}(q)$

This is true enough. Consequently, there is a positive power of $x$ in $q$ or a positive power of $y$ in $q$. Unfortunately there is a big problem: [that isn't enough to conclude that $q$ is primary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/728535/29335). So the approach does not get you to where you want to be.

You could go a little deeper and [observe something](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/649192/29335) about maximal ideals containing $q$. Or you could [perform the most likely computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/649179/29335).

Comment: My homework problem actually doesn't ask for the "primary" part, just enough to show the relation of x in q or y in rad(q). I copied the first sentence of my question from somewhere else and I didn't remember to modify that. Thank you.